How to use 2 different databases but share the same user in wordpress
I have 2 wordpress websites on the same server, one is bloo.com and the other is forum.bloo.com.  each site has its own database, they have their own wp_content, each has its own file separately, but I want the 2 sites to share the same user, if the user registers on bloo.com, he can connect to bloo.  com and forum.bloo.com with the same login info.
As each site has separate files, is it possible for me to make the sites use the same wp_users and wp_usermeta, while the other tables will always be different from each website.
I only want the site to have wp_users and wp_usermeta in common.  Basically, I want to create a user who registers on bloo.com or forum.bloo.com can connect to the 2 sites with a single account with this login info.
Please tell me how I can do this and if there is a code I should use please share it with me, thanks in advance.
